# What is the best approach to insert (update) a lot of entities using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jdbc

I I need to execute something like

```
   for (int i = 0; i<=moreThanThousand; i++){
       Entity e = new Entity();
       insertEntity(e);
   }
```

or

```
for (Entity e: moreThanThousandEntities){
       updateEntity(e);
   }
```

Is there some batch mechanism in Hibernate? Does it make sense to perform this work in several threads? What is the best practice? 
With JDBC I would use addBatch() and executeBatch() methods of PreparedStatement but I'm not expert in Hibernate. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can define the batch size using:

```
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size 20
```

The inserting/updating in batches is easy:

```
for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(.....);
    session.save(customer);
    if ( i % 20 == 0 ) { //20, same as the JDBC batch size
        //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

For more details, have a look [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-inserts).

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing a great volume of data, like as importing data every day and you have a very small window of processing to do that, the best approach unfortunately is to access your DB directly using JDBC, consider all these:

- Garbage collector - Avoid to construct and free millions of objects on critical operations
- Data importing apart from data processing - Try to process the data inside database using stored procedure. There you can reach the best performance when relating the data with others business data (usually needed).
- Data physical validation - Parsing operations and physical validation you shall prefer to do only on importing phase, leave to your stored procedures only the cleaned data to be validated against others business data inside DB.
- Pipeline - Consider to construct a pipeline of processing to do several phases on the same time. When you are importing data, the data already imported is asynchronously processed by stored procedures, and so on.

I can tell you that on systems when we should process about 8 millions of records (I haven't the volume in bytes but is big) daily during only 2 hours by day, thus was the only way to reach the best performance even using the highest hardware allowed.

I hope i have gave to you a new useful approach to consider.